# Bands along pipe curve (or how to get radial coordinate of curve in shader node)?

Tags: hair, shader-nodes

So, I have this... idea I want to try for creating stylized fur. However, in order for it to work, I need to be able to distribute random lines *along* a hair.

I'm pretty sure I can figure out the randomization and translating it into color. What I'm missing is how to get the position "around" the hair. (I need it in a shader node, obviously.)

Given a curve-with-thickness, it's natural to think of it as having a cylindrical coordinate system, $(r, \theta, z)$. I can get $r$ and $z$ easily enough; they are 'Thickness' and (very odd choice of name) 'Intercept', respectively, from a 'Curve Info' node.

**How do I get $\theta$?**

Alternatively, how can I create a 1D noise texture along hairs where the stripes follow the hair curve?

---

Ignoring the "random lines" bit (as noted, that's easy if I can get *θ*), say I was trying to make hairs that look like (the outside of) this white-stripe-on-blue (without the black markings) wire:
[image]

Obviously, a color map that maps $[0, x)$ to white and $(x, 1]$ to blue, for a suitably chosen $x$ (eyeballing, I'd say $x ≈ 0.2$) fed by a Math node to scale $\theta$ to $[0, 1]$, would do the trick... *but I need $\theta$*.